# How to effectively unserialize collection from comma-separated string generated by toString()?

Tags: java, serialization, collections

Let's say we have a collection (a `HashSet`) of strings and we apply `toString()` function after which write the output into a file. the output is just like this:

```
[something, here, some, strings]
```

Is there a standard way to extract this back into a `HashSet`?

Comment: Did you look into serialization/de-serialization?